# How to work the callback function in for loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm doing codeigniter validation..The validation code is working properly without id.What changes i made for this

```
for($i=0;$i<count($expense_id_array);$i++)
{
    $required_id = TRIM($expense_id_array[$i]);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment_'.$required_id, 'Comments', 'required|Myalpha['.$required_id.']');
}
```

**callback**

```
public function Myalpha($id)
{
    $comment=$this->input->post('comment_'.$id);
    if ( !preg_match('/^[a-z .,\-]+$/i',$comment) )
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('Myalpha['.$id.']', 'The %s field may only contain alphabetical characters.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Something happened i append the id.What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prepend `callback_` to your method in validation. See from [documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods)

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('comment_'.$required_id, 'Comments', 'required|callback_Myalpha['.$required_id.']');
```

Thus within the message, you don't need to include id.

```
$this->form_validation->set_message('Myalpha', 'The %s field may only contain alphabetical characters.');
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is so unclear , but assuming your callback are not functioning , it is because you're missing "callback_" on your code .. and this is the right syntax ..

```
for($i=0;$i<count($expense_id_array);$i++)
{
    $required_id = TRIM($expense_id_array[$i]);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment_'.$required_id, 'Comments', 'required|callback_Myalpha');
}
```

**CALLBACK**

```
public function Myalpha($id) 
{
    $comment=$this->input->post('comment_'.$id);
    if ( !preg_match('/^[a-z .,\-]+$/i',$comment) )
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('Myalpha', 'The %s field may only contain alphabetical characters.');
        return false;
    }
}
```